# Wix will not touch AppData Folder During Install

Tags: wix

So i've been working on this problem for days. My installer simply will not add anything into, or remove anything from, the roaming AppData folder in windows. I'm new to Wix and this is my first installer. The program is also shipped with a Bootstrapper which installs various prequisitaries and the .NET Framework. The code I have used is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="USBackup" Language="1033" Version="!(bind.fileVersion.USBackup.exe)" Manufacturer="Ed Rose" UpgradeCode="795ea019-054a-4f34-8c9a-cb4e607897c0">
    <Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="..\USBackup\resources\usb.ico"/>
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
<Condition Message='This setup requires the .NET Framework 4.5 installed.'>
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
</Condition>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Setup" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
  <ComponentRef Id='AppDataDir'/>
  <ComponentRef Id='DevicesDir'/>
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="USBackup" />
        </Directory>

        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="USBackup">
                <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="{B01A59A5-ADA0-43FD-B14F-D479CD002E72}">
                    <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
                    <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

  <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder" Name="CommonAppData">
    <Directory Id="AppDataDir" Name="USBackup">

      <Component Id="AppDataDir" Guid="{573BF504-1F52-40FE-A78A-96F43924379E}">
        <RemoveFolder Id="AppDataDir" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
      </Component>

      <Directory Id="DevicesDir" Name="Devices">
        <Component Id="DevicesDir" Guid="{E145EA47-109F-42E7-ABAB-4E9A87FEC464}">
          <RemoveFolder Id="DevicesDir" On="uninstall"/>
          <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>

    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

        <Component Guid="{9D9BA12C-0859-46F0-B5E1-2A59BE96F83D}">
            <File Source="$(var.USBackup.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes">
              <Shortcut Id="start" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="USBackup" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
            </File>
        </Component>

        <Component Guid="{6B473C52-6901-4FAC-A48B-20FC13A49C21}">
            <File Source="..\USBackup\bin\Release\AutoUpdater.NET.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>

        <Component Guid="{6191F8CC-98A8-4424-A846-44DC1EB2A22C}">
            <File Source="..\USBackup\bin\Release\USBackup.exe.config" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>

        <Component Guid="{4E183A88-69DE-49D1-9142-13A2346443AF}">
            <File Source="..\USBackup\bin\Release\USBackup.exe.manifest" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>

  <!--Set to open on startup-->
  <Component Id="RegistryKey" Guid="{8DBAB7DD-D9CD-4EC4-97F9-9A6131B40108}" Shared="yes">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run">
      <RegistryValue Id="startupValue" Action="write" Name="USBackup" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]USBackup.exe" Type="string"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

It builds with no errors or warnings. Why won't it touch the AppData Directory?

Comment: Perhaps you chose the wrong directory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367992(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You might try Process Monitor (procmon, part of Sysinternals tools) to see what happens at run-time.  Is it getting an error trying to open a directory, or perhaps generated the wrong name for it?  It's often very enlightening.

Comment: You have InstallScope="perMachine" .. AppData is perUser

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any reason for it to create it.

Include `<CreateFolder/>`, as such

```
 <Component Id="AppDataDir" Guid="{573BF504-1F52-40FE-A78A-96F43924379E}">
        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work - in fact I had the <CreateFolder /> tag in there at one point but for some reason it wasn't in the snippet I posted - probably me just experimenting. I've tried adding the components to the main ComponentGroup and also have been playing around with diffrent orders of tags in case there is some odd error that stops it working in different orders, but to no avail. Is there anything else that could be stopping it from adding or removing folders from that directory?